# Can someone tell me what this mips question means in english?

Tags: byte, mips

Find the shortest sequence of MIPS instructions that extracts bits 16 down to 11 from register $t0 and uses the value of this field to replace bits 31 down to 26 in register $t1 without changing the other 26 bits of register $t1.
can you help explain this more clearly? or help me to do it?

Comment: Which part is unclear?

Comment: all of it, i just dont even know where to begin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Find the shortest sequence of MIPS instructions that extracts bits 16 down to 11 from register $t0 and uses the value of this field to replace bits 31 down to 26 in register $t1 without changing the other 26 bits of register $t1. can you help explain this more clearly? or help me to do it?

It says that in a 32-bit MIPS register `$t0` where the bits are indexed as 31(most significant bit)-0(least significant bit) take the subset of bits indexed by the range 16-11 (inclusive). So,

```
31 30 29 28 27 26 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 (16 15 14 13 12 11) 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

And, copy them into the register `$t1`'s bit's indexed by the range "31 down to 26",

```
(31 30 29 28 27 26) 25 24 23 22 21 20 19 18 17 16 15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

The rest of the bit's in `$t1` (25-0) should not change.

Can you think of a way of doing it with `srl, sll, or` (shift right, shift left, or)?

> srl $t0, $t0, 11 # t0 = t0 >> 11 
>  sll $t0, $t0, 26 # t0 = t0 << 26 
>  sll $t1, $t1, 5 
>  srl $t1, $t1, 5 
>  or  $t1, $t1, $t0

Do you see what we did here?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MIPS, but this is all about bit manipulation:

Looks like registers in MIPS are 32 bits.
Let's say bits are numbered 0 to 31, the most significant one is the leftmost one and it is bit number 31.

To extract bits 16..11 (6 bits in total) you have to do a 6 bit AND, like $t0 & 0b00000000 00000001 11111000 00000000.

To replace the bits in $t1 it is trickier: first you have to set bits 31..26 to zero, like $t1 & 0b00000011 11111111 11111111 11111111

Next you have to left-shift the source 15 bits (from 16 to 31 there are 15 bits), like $t0 << 15.

And finally you need to OR'em, like $t1 = $t1 | $t0